# How to map OneToOne relationship between POJOs using @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference

Tags: json, jackson, one-to-one

I have read

- http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.com/2010/10/json-jackson-to-rescue.html
- http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.com/2010/10/json-jackson-serialization-narrowed.html
- http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/09/entry_418.html

looking for solutions to map **One-To-One** relationships. However, those demos in the articles are all Many-To-One or One-To-Many. From the demo, I conclude that in most cases, we will annotate the ONE side as @JsonManagedReference and the MANY side as @JsonBackReference.

However, there's no hint about how to map One-To-One. Do you have any idea?

Also, what if it is a bi-directional one-to-one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can think of it as just a special case of one-to-many; so you will annotate reference from 'parent' to 'child' as @JsonManagedReference, and 'child' to 'parent' as @JsonBackReference.

One more document that might be helpful is the one at [FasterXML Jackson Wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences); first example is for one-to-one relationship, and should be applicable for your case.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is quite useful for me. By the way, what if I want to map a Bi-directional One To One?

Comment: Fully bi-directional case is cyclic, so it's not supported currently: it would need proper handling of cyclic graphs (which could then also handle all other combinations, but require metadata in JSON, object ids or such)

Comment: @JsonIdentityInfo will work. [JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity)

Comment: Yes: support was added after I added my comment. Thank you for noting the "new" feature (was added in 2.0).